# Now that 11.04 is out will 10.04 still upgrade to 10.10?

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, upgrade

I have been running 10.10 on my laptop and like it. I would like to upgrade my 10.04 LTS box at home by just enabling normal releases in update manager.

Should this work, or have I caused a problem by waiting past the 11.04 release?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your box will still prompt you for 10.10.

If you skip a release you have to upgrade to that first before going on to the next one. The one exception where skipping works is LTS-to-LTS upgrades.

- [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-10-04-or-10-10-to-11-04)